# Regular Expression for splitting an alpha-numeric string into 3 sections?

Tags: c#, regex

I have many different formats of input strings, and I need to split the input string into 3 sections.  A few examples below (although there are several possibilities):

1A1 = 1, A, 1

123AA44 = 123, AA, 44

AA44 =  empty, AA, 44

44AA = 44, AA, empty

Additional constraints for these sections:

- 1st section is only numeric and is 1-4 characters long
- 2nd section is only alpha and is 1-3 characters long
- 3rd section can be numeric or alpha-numeric and is 1-4 characters long

I have reached the end of my regex knowledge with the code below.  It works for every scenario except when one of the 3 sections is left empty in the input.  Need some help! Thanks.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<Section1>[0-9]{1,4})(?<Section2>[a-zA-Z]{1,3})(?<Section3>[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,4})");
Match match = regex.Match(inputString);

string 1 = match.Groups["Section1"].Value;
string 2 = match.Groups["Section2"].Value;
string 3 = match.Groups["Section3"].Value;
```

Comment: how do you distinguish 2nd from 3rd section? Does the 3rd section always start with a letter?

Comment: 2nd section always ends with a letter and 3rd section always begins with a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<Section1>[0-9]{0,4})(?<Section2>[a-zA-Z]{0,3})(?<Section3>[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,4})");
```

Comment: Yea, that does make more sense! You just missed the zero on the last section.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to add an optional to each section.
And I added the rule to the 3rd section to start with a number

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<Section1>[0-9]{1,4})?(?<Section2>[a-zA-Z]{1,3})?(?<Section3>[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z]{0,3})?");
```